# For particular user, Ms Graph event list returns error

Tags: c#, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm calling MS Graph Rest API with C# SDK. For most of the users, this code runs ok. However, in one case I just received:

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException : Code: UnknownError.

How can I fix this problem, or check what is actually wrong with this request?

Below is the SDK call I'm using to call Rest API:

```
var calendarViewTask = await graphClient.Users[sub.MicrosoftUserId].Calendars[sub.MicrosoftCalendarId]
                .CalendarView.Request(options).Top(200).Filter("type eq 'singleInstance'").Expand($"Extensions($filter=id eq '{GraphHelper.EVENT_EXTENSION_KEY}')").GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

I've checked permissions and it was set correctly, it works for other users. After investigating a little bit I found out the cause for this problem.

This user had multiple recurring events in calendar. When I called for all events in following 100 years, the amount of events was to big and I've received error 500. When asked for 1 year the API returned all the data I've requested for.

My speculation is this is somehow connected to the underlying api and processing of the events by MS Graph before returning data.

The problem is fixed

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting permissions on Azure AD. If not try the below solution and see if that helps.

The permissions that needs to be provided to the app on Azure AD.

Azure application registered on Azure AD needs to provide the below permissions under Microsoft Graph API:
[image]

One thing to keep in mind is you cannot impersonate as logged in user, you have to use client secret.

Also you can go through the below article to help understand finding the correct permissions for Azure Graph API. 
[Permissions for a Microsoft or Azure Active Directory Graph Call](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aaddevsup/2018/05/21/finding-the-correct-permissions-for-a-microsoft-or-azure-active-directory-graph-call/)